# How to open modal just like google calendar modal, on day click event in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I make a bootstrap dialog box for event information. Now I want to open that dialog box just like google calendar dialog box. Like just near to date not on middle of page.

```
<div id="addClassSchedule1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {   
  $('#addClassSchedule1').modal()
},
```

Please open google calendar and click on any date you will get idea about my problem.

Comment: no sir there is not any type of error in console . I just want to open my modal as like google calendar modal.

Comment: "I want" is not a _problem_. It's just a requirement. You've written some code. Now what is the issue when you run it? Does the modal show up, or not? Or are you asking how to place the event data from fullCalendar into your modal? I don't see any code where you tried to do that. Did you have a problem with it? As I say, it's unclear exactly what you need help with.

Comment: @ADyson sir, you are absolutely correct, this is my requirement not a problem. If I click on some date, modal is popup near the that date. not in middle of the page. This is what i exactly want.

Comment: Right but I think you have missed the point that this is not just a free write my code service...you don't just turn up with a set of requirements and then we give you a full solution for free, without any effort from you. You need to ask us a specific question about your code, e.g. to help fix a bug, explain a concept, or ask about a detail of the code.  So far you haven't done any of that as far I can see. What have you researched in relation to your requirement? What did you try? What went wrong? What problem or concept do you need help with?

Comment: P.S. Displaying a popup relative to another element is something you can do with bootstrap already, it should be possible to research it without much difficulty. If you then try to implement something and get stuck, that would be the time to ask us about it. Thanks.

Comment: Having said all that, here is a hint to get you going: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Comment: You might also find https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayRender a useful callback in fullCalendar to use for setting up your popover. Or alternatively https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayClick might be suitable. Although if you are using this to allow the user to create new events, then fullCalendar recommends you do this via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-callback rather than dayClick - this gives the user the opportunity to drag (not just click) to select multiple days, and/or select specific times within the day (if using an "agenda" view)

Comment: ok @ADyson sir i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#addClassSchedule1').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sir can you please open google calendar and click on date then a modal is open just near the date where you click. I want that functionality in my project, in my project modal is opening perfectly fine not any issue on this, but it is opening on middle of page.

Comment: For your case, you might want to use Popovers instead. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/